# Service Fabric Sample Application missing log messages when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure, logging, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to get the default Service Fabric app logging to work in Azure the same way it does locally.

In Visual Studio 2019 v16.4.5 I created the sample Service Fabric stateless application .Net Core 3.1.
Everything built and runs locally OK.
In the Diagnostics Event window I can see the application log messages "Working-1522" this if from the sample source code:

```
ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Working-{0}", ++iterations);
```

But.. When I deploy to Azure it deploys OK and runs OK but I no longer see the "Working-1522" messages in any of the storage WADServiceFabricSystemEventTable or WADServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable tables.
I don't see the messages anywhere.

I am not using Application Insights. The nodes have the IaaSDiagnostics Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics Extension, with these Settings:

```
{
  "WadCfg": {
    "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
      "overallQuotaInMB": "50000",
      "sinks": "applicationInsights",
      "EtwProviders": {
        "EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration": [
          {
            "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors",
            "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "1",
            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
            "DefaultEvents": {
              "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableActorEventTable"
            }
          },
          {
            "provider": "Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services",
            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
            "DefaultEvents": {
              "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricReliableServiceEventTable"
            }
          }
        ],
        "EtwManifestProviderConfiguration": [
          {
            "provider": "cbd93bc2-71e5-4566-b3a7-595d8eeca6e8",
            "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Information",
            "scheduledTransferKeywordFilter": "4611686018427387904",
            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT5M",
            "DefaultEvents": {
              "eventDestination": "ServiceFabricSystemEventTable"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "SinksConfig": {
      "Sink": [
        {
          "name": "applicationInsights",
          "ApplicationInsights": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "StorageAccount": "wad34xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-aggregation-wad)?
You seem to be missing the storage account details:

```
"type": "IaaSDiagnostics",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "protectedSettings": {
        "storageAccountName": "[parameters('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')]",
        "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('applicationDiagnosticsStorageAccountName')),'2015-05-01-preview').key1]",
        "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/"
        },
```